# How to handle autocapitalize for things like i.e., e.g.?

Tags: capitalization, sentences, auto-capitalize-mode

In auto-capitalize mode, whenever Latin abbreviations such as `e.g.` or `i.e.` are entered, auto-capitalize mode seems to be too eager, and capitalizes the first letters `E` and `I` after the first period `.` is entered.

*Is it possible to configure the mode to trigger auto-capitalize only after the period **plus a whitespace** is entered?*

(This seems to be a more natural way to capitalize to me.)

Comment: Maybe [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430229/how-to-instruct-emacs-auto-capitalize-mode-to-automatically-lowercase-any-word-t) could inspire you. I don't use this mode, so I can't tell.

Comment: @FirminMartin: FYI: You can post an answer here that essentially repeats what that SO answer says. (SE doesn't consider posts across areas to be duplicates.)

Comment: @Drew Thanks, it's good to know. I just don't have enough time to 1) invest on a package I personally don't use, 2) make sure that the answer is still relevant (it is written 7 years ago) and 3) adapt it to OP issue (although it's practically the same). That's why I suggest OP to test & tweak the answer as they are already familiar with the package and issue. Perhaps they would write a more precise answer than I would. But, yeah, I will definitely do so if the occasion is present.

Comment: @FirminMartin Thanks! I think the linked question does provide a practical answer to my question here, esp. the advice to use `C-q .'` instead of `.` . I had thought that changing the trigger condition is a natural fix. But  `M-x quoted-insert` is a native solution.

Comment: @tinlyx That's nice to hear! Once you're satisfied, you can write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26590746/683218)@Frimin, there are at least two ways to disable things like `e.g.`, `i.e.`.

One is to use regular expressions and `auto-capitalize-predicate` to filter them out explicitly in `init.el`:

```
(setq auto-capitalize-predicate
      (lambda () (not (looking-back
           "\\([Ee]\\.g\\|[Ii]\\.e\\)\\.[^.]*" (- (point) 20)))))
```

The second is to manually replace the triggering whitespace or punctuation character with `M-x quoted-insert` (e.g. `gnu C-q .`).